# Get Memory , CPU for process C++

Tags: python, c++, memory, process, cpu

I need to get all available information on each process running in the computer
that includes : CPU information such as cpu usage and so on with Memory.

I've used CreateToolhelp32Snapshot and Process32Entry to obtain information such as Process name, Process ID, num of threads.

then used OpenProcess with the ID i got from above to get memory info.

Code runs good. But OpenProcess returns Denied_access on a lot of Processes so i wasnt able to get their Memory info which is not good.

But it is possible since i can get this information from psutil libary (Python)

I've come accros WMI too but doesn't give a lot info about the memory..

Is there any method to bypass OpenProcess's Access denied and still get the info?

Is there another method to get all this information per Process?

And if there isn't any good solutions for above :
There is option to run python script and get the info to a matrix which is coded in C++ upon the memory? I don't want to write it to a file and read in C++ from the file because it is very slow and time is critical..

This is the code if its matter :

```
void GetMemoryInfo(DWORD processID, int index, ProcessT list[])
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;

// Print the process identifier.

printf("\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID);



// Print information about the memory usage of the process.

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    if (NULL == hProcess)
        cout << GetLastError();

    if (GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)))
    {
        list[index].pMemory.PagefileUsage = pmc.PagefileUsage;
        list[index].pMemory.PeakPagefileUsage = pmc.PeakPagefileUsage;
        list[index].pMemory.PeakWorkingSetSize = pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize;
        list[index].pMemory.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage = pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
        list[index].pMemory.QuotaPagedPoolUsage = pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
        list[index].pMemory.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage = pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
        list[index].pMemory.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage = pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
        list[index].pMemory.PageFaultCount = pmc.PageFaultCount;
    }
}
int showProcessInformation(ProcessT list[]) {
    int i = 0;
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnapshot) {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
        if (Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe32)) {
            do {
                list[i].pExeName = pe32.szExeFile;
                list[i].pID = pe32.th32ProcessID;
                list[i].thredcnt = pe32.cntThreads;
                GetMemoryInfo(list[i].pID, i, list);
                i++;

        } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe32));
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
}

return i;
```

}

Comment: Only a privileged process should be able to get this information about processes owned by other users.

Comment: I've tried run it as administrator. No success. How do I make this process privilege @barmar